# How to get a custom page through plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am developing a Wordpress plugin handling a calender in which it is possible to sign up for a given event. As part of this, I want to make a custom page for the signup-form and confirmation message to the client, however I have no idea how to do this.

I have seen that there is a wp_insert_post() function to insert a new post, but I need a page with custom plgin content (signup form) instead.

Is this even possible to do and how do I do this if it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_insert_post` for creating the page.

```
<?php
    $content = '<Sign up form content>';
    wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_title' => 'My page',
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_type' => 'page', //VERY IMPORTANT
        'post_status' => 'publish/draft'
    ));
```

Check it.

Comment: Just one more question: how do I then access this page using a link?

Comment: Check the `Pages` section for your custom page and check it's permalink.